Nvidia driver problems after upgrading to 24.04
I upgraded my system today to version 24.04 and found a whole host of applications no longer working. The first thing I noticed is that things like the systems settings and file manager refuse to open. I tried reinstalling gnome-control-center but that didn't work. After some googling and trial and error I noticed it might be an issue with my graphic card  drivers. After executing the following command my file explorer, settings and the like started working again:
sudo apt-get install libnvidia-egl-wayland1

Games still don't work though. Some open but are extremely choppy and most simply won't open. Sometimes I will even get "screen glitches" while watching YouTube. First thing I tried is updating my Nvidia drivers with sudo ubuntu-drivers install but no change. It says all my drivers are up to date.
I'm unsure what to do next. Any hints on what to do next would be appreciated.
So my card is a RTX 3080 Ti. I ran the nvidia-smi command to see the details of my drivers and it says I have version 535.183.01. I am using Ubuntu and my exact kernel version is 6.8.0-39-generic

You have asked a graphics question but have not included any graphics details in the question. What graphics driver are you using? What kernel are you using? is a good place to start.

Fair point yeah. So my card is a RTX 3080 Ti. I ran the nvidia-smi command to see the details of my drivers and it says I have version 535.183.01. I am using Ubuntu and my exact kernel version is 6.8.0-39-generic

Loc If you want to fix some of the apps you can try https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

For your 3080, the Nvidia driver 555 would improve wayland behavior.  The graphics-drivers PPA offers the stable 555.58.02, so add the repository with add-apt-repository:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

Then update:
sudo apt update

and see if the ubuntu-drivers script or the Software & Updates/Additional drivers app offers the 555 drivers.
At this point, you may also just directly install the newly available drivers (550, 555,...) if you want (ubuntu-drivers was having some problems earlier, but they have been fixed).

This seems to have mostly fixed the issue. After upgrading, the one game that opened but was laggy suddenly ran really smooth. After also reinstalling Wine the other games started running again and ran a lot smoother than before. There's just one of my Steam games that still doesn't work but that's probably going to be something else that happened during the update seeing it's the only exception.
